# React: How to handle cycle dependencies on useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, immer.js

I have a React hook that receives a list of file URLs, which it downloads and saves into a local cache. The challenge I face is that I cannot figure out a good way to listen for changes in the `cacheQueue` state. When a new item is added to the `cacheQueue`, I would like to receive it in the useEffect and submit it to the `cacheQueue`. However, the challenge is that I make some changes to the cacheQueue within the `useEffect` to reflect the item's cache state, and this creates a cycle that goes on forever. How can I write my useEffect to avoid this endless loop?

```
  const useExternalCache = () => {
const [filePath, setFilePath] = useState('');

const [cacheQueue, setCacheQueue] = useImmer<CacheQueue[]>([]);

const handleAdd = useCallback((queueItem: CacheQueue) => {
  setCacheQueue((draft) => {
    if (!draft.find((item) => item.uri === queueItem.uri)) {
      draft.push(queueItem);
    }
  });
}, []);

const handleAddAll = useCallback(
  (queueItems: CacheQueue[]) => {
    setCacheQueue((draft) => {
      const unique = Lodash.xorBy(queueItems, draft, 'uri');
      if (!Lodash.isEqual(unique, draft)) {
        unique.forEach(handleAdd);
      }
    });
  },
  [handleAdd],
);

const updateCacheQueueItem = useCallback((update: CacheQueue) => {
  setCacheQueue((draft: CacheQueue[]) => {
    const toUpdate = draft.find((item) => update.uri === item.uri);
    if (toUpdate) {
      const idx = draft.indexOf(toUpdate);
      const current = draft[idx];
      draft[idx] = {...current, ...update};
    }
  });
}, []);

const clearQueue = useCallback(() => {
  setCacheQueue((draft: CacheQueue[]) => {
    draft.splice(0, draft.length);
  });
}, []);

const onAddToQueueDone = async ({
  id: uri,
  result,
}: {
  id: string;
  result?: Promise<string>;
}) => {
  const cacheURI = await result;
  cacheURI && setFilePath(cacheURI);
};

const addItemsToCacheQueue = useAsyncQueue({
  concurrency,
  done: onAddToQueueDone,
});

const getPathByUri = useMemo(
  () => async (uri: string, headers?: any) => {
    const result = await cache.getPathByUri(uri, headers);
    if (result) {
      const updatedUri =
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + result : result;
      return updatedUri;
    }
    return result;
  },
  [],
);

const addToCacheQueue = useCallback(
  ({uri, headers}: CacheQueue) =>
    addItemsToCacheQueue.add({
      id: uri,
      task: async () => {
        //Update item to reflect it is in caching queue
        updateCacheQueueItem({
          uri,
          isCaching: true,
        });
        const result = await getPathByUri(uri, headers);
        //Update item to reflect it is cached
        updateCacheQueueItem({
          uri,
          isCaching: false,
          isCached: true,
        });
        return result;
      },
    }),
  [addItemsToCacheQueue, updateCacheQueueItem],
);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('cacheQueue changed: ', cacheQueue);
  const newlyAdded = Lodash.filter(
    cacheQueue,
    ({isCaching, isCached}) => !(isCaching || isCached),
  );

  console.log('BgetPathByUri: adding', newlyAdded.length);
  Lodash.forEach(newlyAdded, (item) => addToCacheQueue(item));
}, [cacheQueue]);

return {handleAddAll, filePath, getPathByUri};
```

};

Comment: have you tried to update the dependencies of all your useCallbacks and useEffects? All of them missing dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/) has helped, instead of using the entire `cacheQueue` as a dependency like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
console.log('prevCacheQueue changed: ', cacheQueue);
const newlyAdded = Lodash.filter(
  cacheQueue,
  ({isCaching, isCached}) => !(isCaching || isCached),
);

console.log('BgetPathByUri: adding', newlyAdded.length);
Lodash.forEach(newlyAdded, (item) => addToCacheQueue(item));
}, [cacheQueue]);
```

Use a part of it you know will only change if something has really really changed and stick to primitive types, so my code now looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
console.log('prevCacheQueue changed: ', cacheQueue);
const newlyAdded = Lodash.filter(
  cacheQueue,
  ({isCaching, isCached}) => !(isCaching || isCached),
);

console.log('BgetPathByUri: adding', newlyAdded.length);
Lodash.forEach(newlyAdded, (item) => addToCacheQueue(item));
}, [cacheQueue.length]);
```